# Intellij IDEA how to "Open with live server"

Tags: visual-studio, intellij-idea

I am writing a little project in Intellij IDEA, but tutorials are on Visual Studio, where a teacher uses **open with live server** command to run HTML code. How it is possible to do simply in Intellij IDEA? Try to open like HTML file or run it, but there is empty page instead of map view

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

[This article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/live-editing.html) will give you an overview of the **Live Edit** feature in IDEA and basic guidance on how to fine-tune its components.

In short, you need ['Live Edit' plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7007-live-edit) installed and enabled in your IntelliJ IDEA and a debugging session started for your HTML file (`Shift+F9`). Once debug is started, IDEA will open your HTML in a Chrome tab and any changes you make in the code will be automatically reflected in the browser.

Comment: According to the linked article, "JavaScript and TypeScript, JavaScript Debugger -  The plugins are available only in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate..."

The plugins are available and work fine in RubyMine, and I would guess any other paid version of an IntelliJ-based IDE. I can't fully test that because the only paid versions I have are RubyMine and IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.